# Split up line with arbitrary many groups

Tags: bash, sed

I have many files with many entries (one entry per line) which I have to filter through a sequence of greps and seds. The lines are of the form

```
a
x, y
u --> v, w
s --> p, q, r
```

One the steps is splitting up the lines containing `-->` such that the left-hand side and each of the comma-separated entries on the right side (of which there can be arbitrary many) end up on different lines. I.e., the above lines should become:

```
a
x, y
u
v
w
s
p
q
r
```

Separating the left side from the right side is quickly done:

```
echo "u --> v, w" | sed 's/\(.\+\)\s*\-\->\s*\(.\+\)/\1\n\2/'
```

Gives me

```
u
v, w
```

But this seems to be a dead end in that I cannot then pipe this on to splitting on the comma, since that would also split the `x, y`.

So, I am wondering if there is a way to completely split up such lines in a sed command, or do I have to turn to, e.g., awk (or just go to Python)?  It would be preferable to keep this a bash pipe sequence.

Comment: Can't you first split off the right hand side `u --> v, w` => `u --> v\nw` and then remove the `-->`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '/-->/ {gsub(/-->|,/,RS)}1' inputfile|column -t
a
x,  y
u
v
w
s
p
q
r
```

OR as Anubhav suggested to avoid pipe:

```
awk '/-->/ {gsub(/[ \t]*(-->|,)[ \t]*/ , ORS)} 1' inputfile
```

Comment: You can remove `column -t` using: `awk '/-->/ {gsub(/[ \t]*(-->|,)[ \t]*/ , ORS)} 1' file`

Comment: The first version, using the `column`, inserts an extra space in `x, y`, making it `x,  y` - the second one does not, so I'm going to use that :)

Answer (score 3):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk -F'[ \t]*-->[ \t]*' -v OFS='\n' '{gsub(/,[ \t]*/, OFS, $2)} 1' file

a
x, y
u
v
w
s
p
q
r
```

Comment: I was taking similar approach, without the `\t` consideration... `awk -F' *--> *' -v OFS='\n' '{gsub(/, */,"\n",$2)} 1'`

Comment: Yes that's nice, I have edited my answer using your shorter awk command

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a command group when you match `-->`.  In this group, you replace `-->` with newline, print up to the newline, discard the portion you printed, then replace commas in the remainder:

```sed
#!/bin/sed -f

/\s*-->\s*/{
s//\n/
P
s/.*\n//
s/,\s*/\n/g
}
```

Results:

```
a
x, y
u
v
w
s
p
q
r
```

---

Alternatively, in GNU sed, you could use the `T` command to skip processing of the right-hand side unless you match and replace the `-->`:

```sed
#!/bin/sed -f

s/\s*-->\s*/\n/
Tend
P
s/.*\n//
s/,\s*/\n/g
:end
```

This produces the same output, as required.

---

I've assumed throughout that you don't want to split any commas on the left-hand side, so that

```
foo, bar --> baz
```

becomes

```
foo, bar
baz
```

If that's not the case (perhaps if you know there will be no comma to the left of `-->`), then you don't need `P` or `s/.*\n//`, and the script is as simple as

```
/\s*-->\s*/!n
s//\n/
s/,\s*/\n/g
```

Comment: Thnx! Even though I would personally prefer this solution (for using only `sed`), the selected one is a little shorter and a one-liner ...